# Pyramid read http data

Tags: python, rest, pyramid, cornice

```
APIURL ='http://localhost:6543/api/patches/alice_8b84090712bce46e15a8107839cefe/e5678'
data = {
    'patch_id' : 'e5678',
    'queue_id' : 'alice_8b84090712bce46e15a8107839cefe',
}
response = requests.get(APIURL, data=data)
```

I have the above code to test a cornice pyramid REST api.

However I am having trouble reading data entered through the `data=data` parameter.

This is the server function for this endpoint:

```
@resource(collection_path='/api/patches', path="/api/patches/{queue_id}/{patch_id}")
class Patch(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def get(self):   
        """
        """
        queue_id = self.request.matchdict.get('queue_id', '')
        patch_id = self.request.matchdict.get('patch_id', '')
        data = {
            'queue_id': 'e12525e1f90ad5e7395a965',
            'patch_id': 'a9651a8259a666c0032f343',
            'node_id': 'bef3a2adc76415b2be0f6942b5111f6c5e5b7002',
            'message': 'This is a patch on feature2.',
            'datetime': '.....',
        }

        #TODO call the patch method to get the public attributes

        return {'error':{}, 'data': data}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requests is ignoring the data provided in the `data` parameter as [that parameter is used to provide the *body* of the response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Request) (and `GET` doesn't have a body).  If you are fine with passing query-string arguments - that is:

```
http://localhost:6543/api/patches?queue_id=12345&patch_id=910
```

then you can use the `params` keyword argument instead:

```
requests.get(APIURL, params=data)
```

Otherwise, you can construct your URL using [`urljoin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) from `urlparse` in the standard library:

```
APIURL = "http://localhost:6543/api/patches"
with_queue = urljoin(APIURL, queue_id)
with_patch = urljoin(with_queue, patch_id)
response = requests.get(with_patch)
```